# vba extract array from array of arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, string, vba

I have a number of arrays that have different strings in them like

```
array1() = Array("one","two","three")
array2() = Array("siz","help")
```

I combine the strings into an array of the string arrays

```
bigArray() = Array(array1(),array2(),...)

For k = 0 To # in bigArray
    reason = causes(xValue, bigArray(k))
Next
```

however I get an error at bigArray(k) when I try to pass it to the function

```
Public Function causes(xValue As String, keyWords() As Variant) As String
```

Comment: what error do you get? It might be able to resolve by doing `keywords as Variant` (without the parentheses).

Comment: Is `bigArray()` declared? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The empty parentheses on the left-hand-side of the assignment are redundant and confusing, remove them.

I presume `bigArray` is declared as such, if at all:

```
Dim bigArray [As Variant]
```

> If it's not declared, specify `Option Explicit` at the top of your module (**always** do this!), and declare every variable you're using - otherwise you allow VBA to happily compile & run typos, and that inevitably turns into embarrassing, hard-to-find bugs, and possibly duplicate questions on Stack Overflow.

A `Variant` can hold anything, including an array, or a *jagged array* (i.e. array of arrays).

The `keywords` parameter though...

```
Public Function causes(xValue As String, keyWords() As Variant) As String
```

Is declared as *an array where each element is a variant*. While the variant element can indeed be an array, when you're passing arrays around as parameters there's no way to say "where each element is *an array* of variant elements", so you'll have a much easier time if you just wrap it in a `Variant` (and then *assert* that you're looking at an array):

```
Public Function causes(xValue As String, keyWords As Variant) As String
    Debug.Assert IsArray(keyWords)
    Debug.Assert IsArray(keyWords(LBound(keyWords))
```

---

Your `For` loop is assuming what the lower boundary is:

> ```
>  For k = 0 To # in bigArray
> ```

A loop that's not making any assumptions would be:

```
For k = LBound(bigArray) To UBound(bigArray)
```

Comment: worked great the assert call did the trick. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @RichardD `Debug.Assert` only serves as a programmatic breakpoint that's useful for debugging - it halts execution when the assertion fails, that's all it does; making the parameter a `Variant` is what fixes it =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon When you say it halts when it fails, do you mean when it returns `False`?

Comment: @dwirony `Debug.Assert` doesn't return anything, but it does take a `Boolean` parameter. `Debug.Assert False` is essentially identical to an actual breakpoint, yeah.